# ionic iframe src https don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, ionic-framework

Why if the URL address starts with `http` - the application is launched on the phone. If the URL address starts with `https`, the application does not work.

```
let frame = $('<iframe src="http://2016.goldensite.ru/" ></iframe>');
let frame = $('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wyVM1evRxNw" allow-navigation href="*" ></iframe>');
```

On the computer, the application works with both `https` and `http`.

Comment: allow-navigation href="*"  - accidentally added. Don't take it for a mistake.